# Performance on scanAll operation vs execute

Tags: aerospike

I used in my `aerospike` recovery process the following `truncate` implementation which gave me great visibility about the number of records which affected during the operation:

```scala
 def truncate(startTime: Long, durableDelete: Boolean): Iterable[Int] = {

    // Setting LUT
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    logger.info(s"truncate(records s.t LUT <= $startTime = ${calendar.getTime}, durableDelete = $durableDelete) on ${config.toRecoverMap}")

    // Define Scan and Write Policies
    val writePolicy = new WritePolicy()
    val scanPolicy = new ScanPolicy()
    writePolicy.durableDelete = durableDelete
    scanPolicy.filterExp = Exp.build(Exp.le(Exp.lastUpdate(), Exp.`val`(calendar)))

    // Scan all records such as LUT <= startTime
    config.toRecoverMap.flatMap { case (namespace, mapOfSetsToBins) =>
      for ((set, bins) <- mapOfSetsToBins) yield {
        val recordCount = new AtomicInteger(0)
        client.scanAll(scanPolicy, namespace, set, new ScanCallback() {
          override def scanCallback(key: Key, record: Record): Unit = {
            val requiresNullify = bins.filter(record.bins.containsKey(_)).toSeq // Instead of making bulk requests which maybe not be needed and load AS
            if (requiresNullify.nonEmpty) {
              recordCount.incrementAndGet()
              client.put(writePolicy, key, requiresNullify.map(Bin.asNull): _*)
              logger.debug {
                val (nullified, remains) = record.bins.asScala.partition { case (key, _) => requiresNullify.contains(key) }
                s"(#$recordCount): Record $nullified bins of record with userKey: ${key.userKey}, digest: ${Buffer.bytesToHexString(key.digest)} nullified, remains: $remains"
              }
            }
          }
        })
```

The problem is that the operation took a lot of time because of the call backs and could not been affected on `production` enviornment, I changed the implementation to the following which instead of taking about `2` hours, the time reduced to `10` minutes.

```scala
def truncate(startTime: Long, durableDelete: Boolean): Unit = {

    // Setting LUT
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    logger.info(s"truncate(records s.t LUT <= $startTime = ${calendar.getTime}, durableDelete = $durableDelete) on ${config.toRecoverMap}")

    // Define Write Policy
    val writePolicy = new WritePolicy()
    writePolicy.durableDelete = durableDelete

    config.toRecoverMap.flatMap { case (namespace, mapOfSetsToBins) =>
      for ((set, bins) <- mapOfSetsToBins) yield {

        // Filter all elements s.t lastUpdate <= startTime on $set
        writePolicy.filterExp = Exp.build(
          Exp.and(
            Exp.le(Exp.lastUpdate(), Exp.`val`(calendar)),
            Exp.eq(Exp.setName(), Exp.`val`(set)))
        )

        val statement = new Statement
        statement.setNamespace(namespace)
        val toNullify = bins.map(Bin.asNull).map(Operation.put).toList
        client.execute(writePolicy, statement, toNullify: _*).waitTillComplete(10.seconds.toMillis.toInt, 1.hour.toMillis.toInt)
      }
    }
  }
```

But the problem is that I don't have any visibility about the affected records like the first method provided me (check out the `logger.debug`)

**Is there a solution how to run with good performance and also provide logs?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using enterprise and that your truncate is only taking LUT into account. The preferred method is to use the `truncate` API. This has a significant advantage over the scan and durable delete method because it will not need to keep a tombstone entry per deleted key, instead, it will have a single entry marking all records in the set as deleted. It also doesn't need to invoke the "tomb raider," which is a periodic disk scan that is searching for tombstones that no longer mark dead records on the device (aka a "cenotaph"). The number of records deleted per node via truncate can be found as [truncated_records](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/#truncated_records).

You can invoke this truncate method with the [truncate](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/index.html#truncate) info command.

---

BTW, you may be able to significantly speed up the first method by settings the [`includeBinData`](https://docs.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/ScanPolicy.html#includeBinData) option to `false` in the scan policy. This results in Aerospike only needing to read and send the in-memory metadata during the scan. I believe we still have to read the device if you've stored keys the record's key with the record.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response - regarding the `truncate`, its not shipped via `XDR`.
`IncludeBinData` is a good option, il ltry it